Experience related to The GA4
Is there any method to learn it step by step, because it is so wide and based on every thing a client can change? Is there any advice related to it?

The best approach is probably just to decide what data you actually need, and find just that.  It collects far more data than most people need (which is why it is such a privacy problem), so you most likely won't ever need to know 90% of it anyway.

The first and most recommended step, if you still have questions about GA, is to familiarize yourself with their guide
This is the official Google product guide that will help you learn it practically from scratch.
Secondly, as Richard mentioned in his comment, decide what data you need and why. For instance, if you are tracking search advertising, those are one set of parameters; if it's organic traffic, then it's another.
